# ORA-02289: sequence does not exist - when using Spring Data JPA with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Database being used is Oracle 11g

```
 Hibernate: select schemaname.col_sqe.nextval from dual
17:06:58.603 [WARN ] -org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:SQL Error: 2289, SQLState: 42000
17:06:58.618 [ERROR] -org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

The sequence is present in the specified schema in the database and the same query returns proper value when executed via sql developer.

The Auto generation configuration is as follow:

```
@Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "COL_GEN", sequenceName = "COL_SQE",schema="SCHEMANAME")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "COL_GEN")
    @Column(name = "COL_ID")
```

Spring JPA configuration is as follow:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: maybe the DB user of your application does not have access to that sequence.

Comment: @Patrick am executing the command in sql developer with the same user

Comment: I just can guess. Guess 1: You set `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings=true` to true. But you dont use the new one. What happens if you delete this property? Guess 2: Set your Schemaname also to your entity on class level. Guess 3: Use `sequenceName 
 = COL_SQE` also for `name` and `generator`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly check if the user which you are using has the read/write privilege

Answer (score 4):

When you use Oracle database, you need to create the sequence manually.
Use this code in your database connection:

```
create sequence YOUR_SEQUENCE_TABLE_NAME start with YOUR_START_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

check for read/write privileges and also check the logs from database and verify if the sequence got executed

Answer (score 0):

even though had schema explicitly included, prefixed to sequence name fixed issue

```
@SequenceGenerator(schema = "schemaname", sequenceName = "schemaname.sequencename")
```

Comment: Where should this be added?